# problem when updating sts or installing extensions

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm working with STS 2.5.0 and I when I tried to install the GWT extension I encountered the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=com.springsource.sts.ide, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,oracle.database.driver.jdk14,10.2.0.1
```

Then I tried to update STS to the newest version (2.5.2) and I got the same error.

Anyone happens to know what's the problem??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the bundle belongs to Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE), and not the STS itself. Try to download and reinstall the latest version of OEPE from [Oracle Technology Framework](http://otn.oracle.com).

Comment: Cool stuff... Works like charm... this was driving me crazy.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the URL that takes you directly to the OEPE download page:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

Eric

Comment: This does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today when trying to update anything from STS 2.9.2 (which is Eclipse-based).  I just added the online repository "http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.1.2.1/juno/repository" to my STS repository, and all the updates started working.